# How do I randomize all tests when running them from a Launcher instance?

Tags: java, junit5

I have a few test classes annotated with @TestMethodOrder; they are performed in a random order, but when I discover and execute them from a Launcher instance, they run in the order that they were discovered (ie TestClassA has its tests randomized, but all of those tests are executed before TestClassB). How do I randomize *all* tests, no matter the order in which they were discovered?